# Mocking dispatch in react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a connected react component (using `react-redux`):

```
doSomething() {
   dispatch(something())
}

render() {
  return (
    <p onClick={doSomething}>{this.props.someText}</p>
  )
}
```

Imagine that the result of clicking in the `p` tag results in the `something` action creator being called which then updates the `someText` value prop.

I need to be able to test that clicking on the p tag does indeed cause a dispatch and in turn that, that causes `someText` to be updated.

How can i mock out `dispatch` so that I can make it mimic how it causes the `someText` prop to be updated?

Comment: What are you using for testing?

Comment: Enzyme, mocha, chai

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but scroll down to **components**  section. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md 

And I would like to suggest you to use bindActionCreators for mapping actionCreators to your props so that you don't have to manually calling dispatch in your component.

Comment: I've read the docs but it doesn't give a relevant example that shows how to deal with dispatch. The docs don't recommend using bindActionCreators for connected components:  'The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.'

Comment: You could create a lastAction reducer (https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/580#issuecomment-133188511) and test that instead.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) along with your test suite (mocha, chai and enzyme).

you may try mocking the function to return some text. Hope this will help

```
sinon.stub(Component.prototype, 'doSomething', function(){
  return 'someText';
});
```

Comment: I am already using sinon to assert that dispatch is called with the correct arguments. I suppose I was hoping there was an accepted way to mock dispatch so that it updated props based on the dispatch. I've decided to instead use enzymes `component.setProps` method to assert that when props are updated my component updates as expected.